# Google Tag Manager setup a custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, google-tag-manager

I am trying to set up a custom domain for the google tag manager. I want to track users using a subdomain of my website (e.g. metrics.domain.com). I followed the steps listed here: https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/custom-domain.

When I checked to see if the new subdomain is working I get the following message:

> Error: Page not found The requested URL was not found on this server.

I tried pinging my subdomain and it appears to be correct:

```
ping ***.***.***

Pinging ghs.googlehosted.com [142.251.36.51] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 142.251.36.51: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=119
Reply from 142.251.36.51: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=119
Reply from 142.251.36.51: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=119
Reply from 142.251.36.51: bytes=32 time=3ms TTL=119
```

Browsing to https://****/g/collect?v=2&tid=***** returns a 404

What step(s) could I have missed?

Comment: Just making sure here. You do realize that that manual is for server-side GTM? It's very different from normal GTM and has a completely different stack of functionality. You can create a server-side GTM container in your GTM account and take a look at it.

Comment: @BNazaruk yes. The point is to set up server-side GTM.

Comment: Would appreciate the solution if you found one, @Nebu. Can't seem to figure this one out myself.

Comment: Have the same problem. [This guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/dependency-serving?tag=gtm) explains it in details. I can GTM debug from my custom domain, but when serving https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XXXXYYY url from my custom domain it returns HTTP 400 / Bad Request

Answer (score -1):

did you update the DNS records in the domain, since you can ping the address but can't access the site, I think there's a problem in the DNS configuration.

Comment: Have the same problem. [This guide](https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/dependency-serving?tag=gtm) explains it in detail. I can Tag Manager Preview / debug from my custom domain, but when I change https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XYZXYZ to https://metrics.mycustomdomain.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-XYZXYZ  it will just respond with HTTP 400 Bad Request.

So currently still serving from tagmanager.google.com, but some browsers (for ex Brave) block Tag Manager.